# What's wrong of my DSolve for Euler's method?

Tags: differential-equations

I try to use method in this link:
http://www.cfm.brown.edu/people/dobrush/am33/Mathematica/euler.html

```
f[x_, y_] := 3 - y^2; (*slope function*)
x0 := 0 (*starting point in x*)
y0 := -2 (*starting value for y*)
xf = 1.0; (*value of x at which y is desired*)
h = (xf - x0)/5.0 (*step size in x*)
soln = DSolve[{f[x, y[x]] == y'[x], y[x0] = y0}, y, x]
plot = Plot[Evaluate[y[x] /. soln], {x, x0, xf}, 
  PlotStyle -> {{Thickness[0.01], RGBColor[1, 0, 0]}}]
X[0] = x0; Y[0] = y0;
X[1] = X[0] + h
Y[1] = Y[0] + f[X[0], Y[0]]*h
plot1 = 
  ListPlot[{{X[0], Y[0]}, {X[1], Y[1]}}, 
    Joined -> True, 
    PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.005], RGBColor[0, 0, 1]}, 
    DisplayFunction -> Identity]
```

Error message:

> DSolve::deqn: Equation or list of equations expected instead of False in the first argument {3 - y[x]^2 == (y')[x], False}.

Comment: use `y[x0] == y0` in place of `y[x0] =y0`?

Comment: @kglr, thx, I replaced, still Error

Comment: Making that correction made everything work for me, but you do need to clear all variables before running again. Easiest to quit the kernel and then run.

Comment: add `ClearAll[f, y, x, x0, y0]` before the first line in your code.

Comment: @kglr do you know how to expand x axle to x=1 or further?I would like to get y[1]

Comment: Erik try `PlotRange -> {{0,1}, All}`?

Answer (score 1):

```
f[x_, y_] := 
 3 - y^2;(*slope function*)x0 = 0;(*starting point in x*)
y0 = -2; (*starting value for y*)
xf = 1.0;(*Value of x at which y is desired*)h = (xf - x0)/
  5.0;(*step size in x*)
soln = DSolve[{f[x, y[x]] == y'[x], y[x0] == y0}, y, x];

X[0] = x0; Y[0] = y0;
X[1] = X[0] + h;
Y[1] = Y[0] + f[X[0], Y[0]]*h;
{plot = Plot[Evaluate[y[x] /. soln], {x, x0, .7}, 
   PlotStyle -> {{Thickness[0.01], RGBColor[1, 0, 0]}}], 
 plot1 = ListPlot[{{X[0], Y[0]}, {X[1], Y[1]}}, Joined -> True, 
   PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.005], RGBColor[0, 0, 1]}, 
   DisplayFunction -> Identity],
 Show[plot, plot1]}
```

[image: fig1]
I will show a fairly accurate explicit Euler solver for problems of this type:

```
h1 = .001; lst = 
 Table[{X[i] = X[i - 1] + h1, 
   Y[i] = Y[i - 1] + f[X[i - 1], Y[i - 1]]*h1}, {i, 1, 700}];

{p2 = ListLinePlot[lst, 
   PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.005], RGBColor[0, 0, 1]}], 
 Show[plot, p2]}
```

[image: fig2]

The analytical solution has two branches, however we can not reach the second branch of the solution by the explicit Euler method.

```
plot = Plot[Evaluate[y[x] /. soln], {x, x0, xf}, 
  PlotStyle -> {{Thickness[0.01], RGBColor[1, 0, 0]}}, 
  PlotRange -> {-200, 200}, PlotPoints -> 200]
```

[image: fig3]

Comment: Thx. do you know how to expand x axle to x=1 or further? I would to get y[1] @Alex Trounev

Comment: The result is correct, maybe your thoughts are not quite right.

Comment: You can not calculate `y[1]` by Euler's method, since the function `y[x]` has a singular point at $x=x_s<1$.

Comment: Try to use an analytical solution `y[1.]/.soln`, then you will get an answer `{4.40963 - 1.52682*10^-15 I, 4.40963 + 1.52682*10^-15 I}`